# Generate Chart from database with Google Chart API

Tags: java, database, servlets, charts

I have a servlet that should generate an image chart from google chart api but its not .. 
here is the code of my servlet :

```
package Graph;

public class Graph extends HttpServlet {

    private static final String DatabaseConnection = null;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Graph() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream());
                System.out.println("SensorGraph");

                response.setContentType("text/html");
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                //sensor Id
                String id = request.getParameter("id");
                // limit in the query
                String limit = request.getParameter("limit");
                DatabaseConnection db_connection =  new DatabaseConnection()._instance;
                Connection connection = null;
                try {
                    connection = db_connection.getConnection();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Statement statement;
                ResultSet resultSet;
                try {
                    statement = (Statement) connection.createStatement();
                    resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from Sensor_Entries order by EntryTime asc limit 5)");
                    String values = "";
                    while(resultSet.next()) {
                        String value = resultSet.getString("EntryValue");
                        values += (value) + ",";
                    }
                    System.out.println(values);
                    values = values.substring(0, values.length()-1);


                    String image = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?" +
                            "chxr=0,0,1000" +
                            "&chxs=0,676767,12.167,-0.5,l,676767" +
                            "&chxt=y" +
                            "&chs=300x225" +
                            "&cht=ls" +
                            "&chco=3D7930" +
                            "&chds=0,1000" +
                            "&chd=t:" + values+
                            "&chg=14.3,-1,1,1" +
                            "&chls=2,4,0" +
                            "&chma=0,6%7C3" +
                            "&chm=B,C5D4B5BB,0,0,0" +
                            "&chtt=Sensor+Values" +
                            "&chts=F00D0D,14.5";
                    if(request.getParameter("img") != null)
                        out.write("<img src=\"" + image + "\" />");

                    statement = (Statement) connection.createStatement();
                    resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from Sensors join " +
                            "(select * from Sensor_Entries order by EntryTime desc) as Sensor_Entries on " +
                            "(Sensors.SensorID=Sensor_Entries.SensorID) where Sensors.SensorID='" + id + "' " +
                            "group by Sensors.SensorID;");

                    ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = (ResultSetMetaData) resultSet.getMetaData();
                    if(resultSet.next()) {
                        writer.write("<table>");
                        for(int i = 1; i < resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount() + 1; i++) {
                            String value = "";
                            int type = resultSetMetaData.getColumnType(i);
                            if(type == Types.INTEGER || type == Types.TINYINT) {
                                value = "" + resultSet.getInt(i);
                            } else if(type == Types.VARCHAR) {
                                value = resultSet.getString(i);
                            } else if(type == Types.TIMESTAMP) {
                                value = resultSet.getTimestamp(i).toString();
                            } else if(type == Types.DOUBLE) {
                                value = "" + resultSet.getDouble(i);
                            }
                            writer.write("<tr>" +
                                    "<td>" + resultSetMetaData.getColumnName(i) + "</td>" +
                                    "<td>" + value + "</td>" +
                                    "</tr>");
                        }
                        writer.write("</table></center>");
                    }
                    else
                        out.write(image);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                } catch (SQLException ignored) { ignored.printStackTrace();  }
            }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
}
}
```

Could you please help me with this problem? .. I am using eclipse ganymede and tomcat 6 for this... 
DatabaseConnection db_connection =  new DatabaseConnection()._instance; is just a connection instance thta I get from a class that I have created purposefully for connecting to the database ...

Comment: Is Google Charts producing any kind of error on the developer console?

Comment: Ganymede? You should consider upgrading to Indigo (I believe that is the current version...)

Comment: @Jon I have now tried in indigo and it still did not produce anything ... No errors in the console no nothing ...

Comment: @mattedgod its not producing any kind of error pal ... its just not showing an image as it should ...

Answer (score 0):

...This issue has now been resolved ... The super() in the constructor for Graph is not needed. that resolves the main issue of the graph not appearing ...

I now need to be able to refresh the whole proccess of getting data from the EntryValues table and regenerate the graph ... has anyone of you any options to how to approach such a problem ? .. say refresh every 10 seconds? ... Please note that I am not trying to refresh the already produced grahp, I want to retrieve data every 10 seconds, store the values in the google graph link that will eventually produce the graph image in the end ...

thanks for your support and please let me know as soon as possible if someone has had to deal with such issue ...